# query on 3 Tables with Join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to join all fields on 3 tables. I've tried nearly 7 queries all of which either take forever to load up (really slow) or throw errors.

I need to join all 3 table on table1 id field. All tables have corresponding id fields.

This is my latest experiment: (throws errors for duplicate rows)

```
SELECT * FROM 
(Select * FROM 
table1 as T1 JOIN 
table2 as T2 ON T1.dep_id=T2.dep_id WHERE 1) as T12
JOIN 
table3 as T3 ON T12.dep_id=T3.dep_id WHERE 1
```

Comment: `throws errors for duplicate rows` --- select query cannot throw such error. And nested query most likely leads to bad performance. Let's start with the query without nested queries, just 2 `INNER JOINS` and see

Comment: Although not very elegant, I think this should work; What is throwing the 'duplicate rows' error? Probably not MySQL.

Comment: Can you explain how you are running those queries? What tools are you using? Also provide the *exact* error message (copy-paste).

Comment: Ah got it: `T12.dep_id` is ambiguous because there are two `dep_id`: one in `T1` and one in `T2`. You are getting an 'ambiguous column name' I assume.

Comment: I'm using MySQL Workbench. Yes exactly  'ambiguous column name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try (UPDATE as per comments from OP):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.DEP_ID = T2.DEP_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE3 T3 ON T1.DEP_ID = T3.DEP_ID
```

Comment: If `T1.DEP_ID = T2.DEP_ID` and `T1.DEP_ID = T3.DEP_ID`, then `AND T2.DEP_ID = T3.DEP_ID` seems a bit redundant.

Comment: `T2.DEP_ID = T3.DEP_ID` --- is not necessary here and can confuse optimizer

Comment: I'm sorry I was not more clear, but I have a specific value I am searching in the T1.dep_id field with a WHERE clause and the result is 0, but there dep_id with my number does exist in the corresponding table. SELECT * test1 T1 
INNER JOIN test2 T2 ON T1.dep_id = T2.dep_id 
INNER JOIN test3 T3 ON T1.dep_id = T3.dep_id
WHERE T1.dep_id = 10008428

Comment: @OldWest does the value exist in all tables or in just one/two of them ?

Comment: @Yahia: it exists in all 3 tables.

Comment: @Yahia: Oh my bad. It does not exist in T3!

Comment: @Yahia: But I need to be able to join T2 still if T3 does not have the value.

Comment: Basically if the value does not exist in T2 or T3, the T1 should still be returned on the match.

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify exactly what you need and add your where condition to your query there.

Comment: @piotrm: thanks for the tip on that. its going on 3am im not thinking straight.

Answer (score 1):

You have columns with the same name which causes the error (`T12.dep_id` is not well-defined, does it refer to original `T1.dep_id` or `T2.dep_id`?).

You could use `USING` which merges two columns with the same name in both sides of the join, and joins them on an equality test. This is convenient when you don't want duplicate columns in the result set:

```
SELECT *
  FROM T1
  JOIN T2 USING(dep_id)
  JOIN T3 USING(dep_id)
```

Note that with the following query, you don't have a column named `T1.dep_id` or `T2.dep_id` nor `T3.dep_id`, you just have `dep_id` available if you want to `SELECT` that column only.

As per comments on Yahia's answer:

```
SELECT *
  FROM T1
  LEFT JOIN T2 USING(dep_id)
  LEFT JOIN T3 USING(dep_id)
```

Answer (score -1):

you have some syntax errors in your code because t12 doesn't exist.
other problem is the declaration of your table
be patient with tables ids.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1,table2 t2,table3 t3 WHERE t1.dep_id=t2.id AND T2.id=T3.dep_id;
```

Comment: T12 is an alias for the subquery.